# Calculating pairwise euclidean distances for observations from different groups in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with observations with three variables (V1 to V3) divided into 3 groups:

```
  V1   V2   V3 group
0.59 0.78 0.91     1
0.72 0.91 0.73     2
1.31 1.21 0.90     3
4.32 1.53 3.20     2
....
```

I would like to calculate euclidean distances between the observations. It is easy to calculate pairwise distances between all observations:

```
df %>% 
    select(-group) %>% 
    dist()
```

But I am also interested in calculating pairwise distances (a) only between observations in the same group (b) between observations not belonging to the same group (e.g., between each observation in group 1 and all observations in group 2 and 3).

For (a), I can do:

```
for (x in unique(df$group){
    df %>%
    filter(group == x) %>%
    select(-group) %>% 
    dist()
}
```

And add the results together; but I am not so sure how to accomplish (b). How should this best be done?

Thanks!

Comment: By (b) do you mean you want ALL pairwise distances except those within the groups?

Comment: @Oka Yes, exactly. This is meant to give some indication of how far apart are the observations in the different groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach splitting computation of distances and extraction by given conditions.

```
##  distance as a matrix
d_m <- df %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  dist() %>% 
  as.matrix()

##  combination of groups
cb_g <- combn(df$group, m= 2)
##  combination of indices
cb_i <- combn(1:length(df$group), m= 2) 

##  extract the values that fit to given conditions
corr_same_grp <- apply(cb_g, 2, function(x) x[1] == x[2]) %>%  # same groups
  { cb_i[, ., drop= F] } %>%           # get indices
  apply(2, function(x) d_m[x[2], x[1]])

corr_diff_grp <- apply(cb_g, 2, function(x) x[1] != x[2]) %>%  # different groups 
  { cb_i[, ., drop= F] } %>%           # get indices
  apply(2, function(x) d_m[x[2], x[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about applying a function similar to in your example over a matrix of variable combinations:

```
library(dplyr)

## define the data frame
df = as.data.frame(cbind(c(.59, .72, 1.31, 4.32),
           c(.78, .91, 1.21, 1.52),
           c(.91, .73, .9, 3.2),
           c(1,2,3,2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(df) = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "group")

## generate a matrix with the unique combinations of groups
combinations = combn(x = unique(df$group), m = 2)

## apply a function over the matrix of group combinations to determine
## the distance between the variable observations
distlist = lapply(seq(from = 1, to = ncol(combinations)), function(i){

  tmpdist = df %>% filter(group %in% combinations[,i]) %>%
    select(-group) %>%
    dist()

  return(cbind(combinations[1,i], combinations[2,i], tmpdist))

})

## combine the list into a dataframe 
dists = do.call(rbind, distlist)

names(dists) = c("group1", "group2", "dist")
```